# Using golang connect to docker container with functional tty

Tags: go, docker, tty, pty

Start simple Docker container in Detached(Background) mode

```
docker run -d --name test ubuntu tail -f /dev/null
```

Here comes my simple golang code where I connect to running container.
In current connection I want to get functional tty.

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "os/exec"
  "bufio"
  "io"
  "os"
  "github.com/kr/pty"
)

func main() {
  cmd := exec.Command("docker", "exec", "-it", "test", "bin/bash")

  tty, err := pty.Start(cmd)
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error start cmd", err)
  }
  defer tty.Close()

  go func() {
    scanner := bufio.NewScanner(tty)
    for scanner.Scan() {
       fmt.Println(scanner.Text())
    }
  }()
  go func() {
    io.Copy(tty, os.Stdin)
  }()

  err = cmd.Wait()
  if err != nil {
    fmt.Println("Error Waiting", err)
  }
}
```

More less it works, but there is couple thinks which is not working as I would run docker command from my terminal.

1. After login I don't see prompt, like `root@ba351b44ca80:/#` only after hitting return it appears, but my currsor is in new line where are no prompt;
2. Also arrow up to get previous command is not working
   Only prints out

   ```
   root@ba351b44ca80:/#
   ^[[A^[[A^[[A
   ```

but behind scene previous command is selected and by hitting return it is executed.

3. After executing command for cursor is not displayed prompt, like

   ```
   root@ba351b44ca80:/# ls
   bin   dev  home  lib64  mnt  proc  run   srv  tmp  var
   boot  etc  lib   media  opt  root  sbin  sys  usr
   <Here my cursor>
   ```

Comment: Why aren't you using the Golang Docker engine API? https://github.com/docker/engine-api/tree/master/client

Comment: @Alkaline Thanks for pointing me in right direction

Here is solution what I needed 

[go-dockerpty](http://go-search.org/view?id=github.com%2Ffgrehm%2Fgo-dockerpty)

Comment: ah good. You can add it as an answer so others will find it. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

[go-dockerclient](https://github.com/fsouza/go-dockerclient) is worth checking out. It is a simple nice abstraction of the Docker remote API. It is used by many opensource projects and is regularly maintained as well.